# Responsive menu not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on the website: insectstings.co.uk, it's responsive and I've made some changes to the original theme.

For some reason in IE8 (maybe others) the menu is displaying as the responsive menu. I've tried changing the media query size but it doesn't help.

Also the main header image is far away from the body content, I've tried inspecting it but with no luck. I hate IE, everything displays fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding repsond.js to IE8 and below. It provides some media query functionality for IE: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, it's strange because this is the standard WordPress theme Twenty 12.

Comment: Awesome. It is odd that WP didn't want to support media queries for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

IE versions below 9 do not support media queries: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

The normal flow of CSS will take over, so IE8 will show whatever you delcare last in your CSS.

EDIT: You might want to read this article, which coveres targeting older IE versions with different CSS.  I have been using this method for a while now and it works really well: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/